# Flink - Datastream type conversion - Error

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to write the processed wordcount in Flink to a kafka topic. Error is ---

"The method addSink(SinkFunction>) in the type DataStream> is not applicable for the arguments (FlinkKafkaProducer09)"

For the code as below -

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> stream1 = stream.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
    .keyBy(0).sum(1);
stream1.print();
env.execute();

stream1.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<String>("WCFKTopic", new SimpleStringSchema(), 
    properties));
env.execute();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error - "The method addSink(SinkFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>>) in the type DataStream<Tuple2<String,Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (FlinkKafkaProducer09<String>)"

Comment: I would be better if you show a minimal working example code with the full stack trace of the exception including the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The input type of your sink function does not match the type of `stream1`.

Try this:

```
new FlinkKafkaProducer09<Tuple2<String, Integer>>(XXX);
```

Comment: This worked, but had to cast argument 2 i.e. new SimpleStringSchema() , but run time error I get another exception - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedSerializationSchema

Comment: Moto is to write the word count to the kafka topic.

Comment: I would be better if you show a minimal working example code with the full stack trace including the line numbers.